# Laravel - upload multiple files

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, laravel

I was searching for some tutorials on how to upload multiple files, for example this: http://tutsglobal.com/discussion/301/how-to-upload-multiple-images-in-laravel-4

There is a `{{ Form::file('images[]', ['multiple' => true]) }}` line that should make from input for selecting multiple files. But the problem is that I can select only one file and not more. What could I do to be able to upload multiple files?

---

This is in my View:

```
{{ Form::open(['action' => 'AdminController@postProject', 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'projectform']) }}

    {{ Form::file('images[]', ['multiple' => 'multiple']) }}

{{ Form::close() }}
```

This is HTML output:

```
<input multiple="multiple" name="images[]" type="file">
```

I just found that I can select multiple files with holding down SHIFT key, but I'd like to be able select files separately, one by one.

Comment: if your form `content-type` set to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: Can you show us the html output of the form?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: maybe its helpful for you.

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp">
     Select images: <input type="file" name="img" multiple>
     <input type="submit">
 </form>
```